# Zip file can be opened in server, but not after downloading it using Angular 1

Tags: java, angularjs, spark-java

We have a legacy code that enables site user to download a file from the server.

Till now, the downloaded files were `CSV` and we had no problem.

Now the server also have a zip file - that contains the CSV.

The server generates the zip file correctly ([used this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress)) and **in the server we can open the zip file, and extract correctly the inside CSV file**.

The problem is when the browser downloads the zip file: The inside CSV file has no CSV suffix and the it can't be open.

The error we get (using 7Zip):

> Unexpected end of data
>
> Warnings:
>
> Headers Error
>
> There are some data after the end of the payload data

**Backend code** for serving the file (Running in `Spark-Java` microservice):

```
    public Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
    fileName = ...
  
    response.raw().setContentType("application/zip");
    response.raw().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

    try (
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutptStream(response.raw().getOutputStream());
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis)) {
        ByteStreams.copy(bufferedInputStream, bufferedOutputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         ....
    }
    return response.raw();
}
```

**Front end** code (Angular 1) for fetching the file:

```
        $scope.downloadFile = function (fileName) {
        $http.get(fileName).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
            var headers = headers();
            var filename = headers['x-filename'];
            var contentType = headers['content-type']

            data = new Blob([data], {type: contentType});
            var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data);

            anchor.attr({
                'href': fileUrl,
                'target': '_blank',
                'download': fileName
            })[0].click();

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.info("download  " + fileName + "  error " + status);
            }
        );
    };
```

Comment: You should show the code that creates the zip file

Comment: I guess the ZIP archive is not complete. Are you using https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy ? Documentation says, the copy method does not flush or close streams...

Comment: @Frito that complete, if it was incomplete the csv file without extension did not create! The problem is the extension adding only!